# there is no point in do+ing except "what verb structure here"?

Tags: gerunds, to-infinitive

Is my sentence below correct?:

> Nobody thinks that he is inferior if not superior, hence there is no point in looking down on anyone except expecting their retaliation

could I also say:

> ... except expect their retaliation

secondly, instead of "in looking down" could I say "no point to look down?" if yes should I later say " except to expect ..."?

Comment: any response those who have some idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After "There is no ..." follows a gerund. You can't use a to-infinitive.

- There is no mistaking American English for Britisch English.
- There is no stopping him.
- There is no point in denying it.

The expression is "There is no point in sth/in doing sth. You can't drop "in" and add a to-infinitive.

Gerund follows also after some expressions with "It is ..." as

- It is no use doing (dg) sth / It is not much use dg sth
- It is useless dg sth
- It is no good dg sth / It is not much good dg sth
- It is worth while reading the book.

From my old school grammar.